# PySpark Set variable that's the name of current loop value

Tags: pyspark

I want to spin through a config file in a loop assigning any options I find to a variable of the same name in my notebook.
So the code is shorter and I don't have a load of try and else steps. I initialize default options at the start and then if I find a config option with the same name it updates it

Config file

```
[file_options]
cfgfilename = 'newfilename.csv'
```

Notebook

```
import configparser
# default options
cfgfilename = 'dummy.csv'
otheroptions_etc = 'hi'

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read({config file path here})

if config.has_section('file_options'): 
  for option in config.options('file_options'):
     {something here to set cfgfilename}= config.get('file_options', option )
  print (cfgfilename)  # and so it comes out as newfilename.csv not dummy.csv
```

Comment: you can't create var names dynamically (at least not easily, AFAIK). the next best option is to use dictionary where the keys act as var names.

Comment: thank you, i just needed to know there was better way and i believe i've solved it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks samKart this is how I solved it using a dictionary

```
# create dictionary with the dummy value pairs
dict_values = { 'filename' : 'dummy.csv',
                'otheroptions_etc' : 'hi'}

# check it has a file options section
if config.has_section('file_options'): 
  # loop through the options in the section
  for option in config.options('file_options'):
     # if that option is in the dictionary..
     if option in dict_values.keys():
       # ... up date it
        dict_values[option] = config.get('file_options', option )

# finally set all the variables to the updated dictionary values
filename= dict_values['filename']
otheroptions_etc= dict_values['otheroptions_etc']
```